# Monodevelop marks everything between #if and #endif as a comment in C# file

Tags: monodevelop, preprocessor-directive

I'm using the version of MonoDevelop bundled with Unity game engine. I never used #if/#endif in C# before, so I never noticed that. I checked this on a new empty file. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played around with this a bit and what I've noticed is that conditional code for a 
"#if DEBUG" block is commented out. It's probably helpful when you've gotten to the point of building your release code. The "debug" test stuff remains in your code, but looks like a comment. Here is what I was playing with to test that out, ymmv:

```
using System;
namespace testConditionalCompile
{
   class MainClass
   {
      public static void Main (string[] args)
      {

#if RELEASE         
          Console.WriteLine("Release code"); 
#endif          

#if DEBUG   
          Console.WriteLine("Debug code");          
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that the conditional code block is not the best way to write it, but I thought it might best illustrate my point above.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this question dealing with either or both the `#if UNITY_IOS ... #elif UNITY_ANDROID` preprocessor directives showing as commented out and/or having strange code formating issues, **Monodevelop only formats code based on whichever platform you have currently chosen in build settings**. So what you see below is intentional, because this code is treated by Monodevelop essentially the same as commented code. The *logic* is that since it will it not be execute, or even included in the build, that it shouldn't be checked in the editor. Thus the formatting / commented-out treatment. I personally find this annoying, because I should be able to write / view formatted code regardless of the current platform I have chosen in build settings.

[image: screenshot]